# jquery mobile does not load carousel plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, plugins, jquery-plugins, carousel

I build a jquery mobile webshop and almost everything works perfect.

This is my script part:

```
$('div[data-role="page"]').live("pageinit",function(event){

$("#foo").carouFredSel({
    responsive  : true,
    scroll      : {
        fx          : "cover-fade"
    },
    items       : {
        visible     : 1,
        width       : 350,
        height      : "100%"
    },
    swipe: {
        onMouse: true,
        onTouch: true
    }
  });
});
```

I want to use the [carouFredSel-plugin](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/) because it is responsive and supports swipe gestures.

The problem is, that the carousel is not loading when you visit the page (http://m.wohnfreuden.de), sometimes it is shown after refreshing the site, sometimes all slides are shown among each other.

Hope you can help me finding the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

First my advise would be to find another carousel. I am talking from my experience.

I have found **`carouFredSel`** plugin one year ago, on a first glance it was a perfect carousel, with large number of possible variations (at that point without swipe function but it was easily fixable).

Unfortunately during the app testing phase it was discovered that plugin for some reason randomly brakes when coupled with **jQuery Mobile** (same problem was not found on desktop web app without jQuery Mobile). Plugin randomly just skips initialization and pictures are show one after another. My personally believe that content height is important to this plugin and jQuery Mobile page height can be calculated correctly only during the pageshow even, but even then there could be some problems.

This was a demo we used to initialize plugin with jQuery Mobile (proof of concept): http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Np3G4/

It only swipes from right to left.

```
$('#carousel').carouFredSel({
    width: '100%',
    height: 250,
    items: 5,
    auto: false,        
    scroll: {
        items: 1,
        duration: aniConf.duration,
        onBefore: function( data ) {          
            data.items.old.eq(1).animate(cssSmall, aniConf);
            data.items.old.eq(2).animate(cssMedium, aniConf);
            data.items.old.eq(3).animate(cssLarge, aniConf);
            data.items.old.eq(4).animate(cssMedium, aniConf);
        }
    }
});

$("#carousel, #home").bind('swipeleft',function(event, ui){
     $("#carousel").trigger("next", 1);
});
```

In the end my advice would be to find another solution cause if developers didn't fix this problem during the past year, I don't think they ever will.